# How can I get the path of the current URL in JavaScript for CodeIgniter usage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example: `http://localhost/example/testpage/this?page=2`

I want just the `http://localhost/example/`

Comment: Use this line window.location.origin+'/'+ window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```js
const url = new URL(window.location.href);

console.log(url.protocol + url.hostname + url.pathname);


// in your case
const testURL = "http://localhost/example/testpage/this?page=2";
const url2 = new URL(testURL);
console.log(url2.protocol + url2.hostname + '/' + url2.pathname.split('/')[1]);
```

Comment: Its just shown the hostname,i need the folder name example http://localhost/example/   (example also in the url)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below line of code :

```
window.location.origin+'/'+ window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]
```